# what the (/^jQuery|deferred/) means

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery api return a JSONP data,it includes

```
{
  //....
  "name": "innerWidth",
  "title": ".innerWidth()"
  //...
}
```

And I really can't clearly know the below codes

```
title = (/^jQuery|deferred/).test(title) ? title : '.' + title;
```

I guess it maybe the difference between in name and title, so what the

```
(/^jQuery|deferred/)
```

means? I guess maybe it's a regular?

Answer (score 2):

It is a regular expression. It is testing whether the value in the `title` variable starts with the word "jQuery" or contains the word "deferred"

Comment: It has to start with jQuery *or* it can contain the word deferred anywhere.

Comment: @BillCriswell Good point, added this clarification to my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
(/^jQuery|deferred/).test(title) ? title : '.' + title;
```

In simple english, this mean if title contains 'jQuery' or 'deferred' then title is equal to its original value otherwise add a '.' infront of title.

Comment: As mentioned by Bill, it has to start with 'jQuery'.